# How to return two values for two foreign keys in same model separately?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

```
  class student(models.Model):
        first_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
        last_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)

  class details(models.Model):
       first_name = models.ForeignKey(student,models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='first name', blank=True, null=True)
       last_name = models.ForeignKey(student,models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='second name', blank=True, null=True)
```

Here, first name and last name are drop downs.With this piece of code drop downs shows studentObjects not first_name and last name values.

we used

```
  def __str__(self):
        return self.first_name
```

but dont know how to send last name.

please help me out.

Comment: not clear what you want to achieve. Could you explain the real problem (not what you think might work). Also: are you aware that a ForeignKey is used to relate objects (and not fields)? I mean... can details be related to two different students? What is a "detail" object?

Comment: update the question.

Comment: `return "%s %s" % (self.first_name, self.last_name)`?

Comment: Your update does not reflect answers to my inquiries. I still don't understand what is a `student` and what is `details`.

Answer (score 0):

I don't like your data structure and I am suspicious that you don't really want  to do it that way.

Let's assume the following:

```
class student(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)

    def __str__(self):
        return "%s %s" % (self.first_name, self.last_name)


class details(models.Model):
    student = models.ForeignKey(student, models.CASCADE)
```

That is used in order to have `student` objects (the students are identified by its `first_name` and `last_name`). And each `details` objects can be related to a single `student` (if you want to change the relation, do so).

The relation is between `student` and its `details`. I am not sure if that is what you want to achieve, but maybe makes sense?